# Writing test logs to Visual Studio Output Pane while not debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, logging, log4net

I'm working on some tests that are using log4net for logging. While the test is running, I don't get any live data at all (except for what's going into my RollingFileAppender). 
Is it possible to modify my project in some way so that the test logs are being shown in some visual studio window in realtime?

I know it can be shown while running the test as debug, but I'd like to do this without running as debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the console isn't attached to your test process so you can't write any messages in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Attach to Process" from the Debug menu to attach the debugger to already running programs.

Or you can run DebugView from SysInternals: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for something that was configurable, or code I could add so that it would do this automatically. We already have a tool to auto-tail the logs, I was hoping to not have to use something so hacky.